# CSS being generated but not saved

Tags: linux, ubuntu, less, phpstorm

I'd configure phpStorm file watcher to generate CSS from a less. Curiously the css is generated (I'd set "Always" to "Show console"), but not saved. How can I solve it?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I solve it?

**Why don't you used template provided by PhpStorm?** It has all fields pre-filled -- you just edit them to fit your project setup. Right now you indeed have configured file watcher to just generate CSS.

You have to either:

- **tick "Create output file from stdout" option** (yep, lessc outputs compiled results this way)
- **or provide generated file name as 2nd parameter in "Arguments" field**, e.g. `--no-color $FileName$ $FileNameWithoutExtension$.css`

Comment: The problem was because I'd import the settings from my Windows version. Thank you for your help.